# Java timeout period to read serial port

Tags: java

I have a code to read serial port through rxtx. But I want that bufferedreader of input-stream should check for specified time that data is coming or not. After timeout it should stop the program or thread which I have started to to read serialReader.

Comment: You may want to investigate [Future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html)s. They give you "timeout"-Functionality: [get with timeout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-)

Comment: You should put the read into a Task that you submit to an ExecutorService. You can then call get( <TIMEOUT-TIME> ) on the resulting Future to wait for a return value or a timeout.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
ExecutorService exec = new Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

// ... where you want to start reading and wait:
Future<String> readResult = exec.submit( new Callable<String>(){
     @Override public String call(){
          // Your reading code here.
     }
} );

try{
   String strResult = readResult.get( 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES );
} catch(TimeoutException tex) {
    // handle Timeout
} catch ( /*... you should also catch other exceptions like */ IOException ioex ){}
```

Just an outline for starters. The read operation will be done on a separate thread. Then on your main thread you wait for it to finish, catching a TimeoutException. If it occurs, you can clean up your resources (close the COM port!!) and exit. If it does not occur, the read was successful.

---

Some resources:

- [Executors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html)
- [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)
- [Future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html)
- [Callable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html)
- Oracle [Executors Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html)

---

Based on your code:

```
public class SerialReaderWithTimeout implements Runnable {
private final InputStream inputStream;
private final ExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

public SerialReaderWithTimeout(InputStream in) {
    inputStream = in;

    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    try {
        bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(FILENAME));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private String readWithTimeout(){
     String strResult = null;

     Future<String> readResult = exec.submit( new Callable<String>(){
     @Override public String call(){
          return br.readLine();
     }} );

    try{
       strResult = readResult.get( 10, TimeUnit.MINUTES );
    } catch(TimeoutException tex) {
        // handle Timeout: NOP -> Just return null
    } catch ( Exception ex ){
        // handle Exception
        throw;
    }

    return strResult;
}

public void run() {
    String inputLine = null;
    try {

        //while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        while ((inputLine = readWithTimeout()) != null) {
            //series.put(num, inputLine);
             //num++;
            bw.write(inputLine);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.flush();
            System.out.println(inputLine);

            if (inputLine.trim().startsWith("DATE") | inputLine.trim().startsWith("REMARK")
                    | inputLine.trim().startsWith("TESTED BY")) {
                serialPort.close();
                inputStream.close();
                br.close();
                bw.close();
                break;
            }
        }   

        //new CompareClass();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Mind that I did not use an IDE to write this nor compiled it, there may be typos and need for some adaption.

Answer (score 0):

```
public ReadWithoutTimings() {
    super();
    num = 1;

    try {


    try {

         serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open("Read1", 2000);
    } catch (PortInUseException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }

    try {
        serialPort.setSerialPortParams(9600, SerialPort.DATABITS_8, SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

    } catch (UnsupportedCommOperationException e1) {
        System.out.println(e1);
    }
    try {
        in = serialPort.getInputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    /*timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {            
        @Override
          public void run() {

            (new Thread(new SerialReader(in))).start();   
              }

        }, time);*/
    (new Thread(new SerialReader(in))).start();  
}

public class SerialReader implements Runnable {


    public SerialReader(InputStream in) {
        inputStream = in;
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        try {
            bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(FILENAME));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        String inputLine = null;
        try {



            while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                //series.put(num, inputLine);
                 //num++;
                bw.write(inputLine);
                bw.newLine();
                bw.flush();
                System.out.println(inputLine);

                if (inputLine.trim().startsWith("DATE") | inputLine.trim().startsWith("REMARK")
                        | inputLine.trim().startsWith("TESTED BY")) {
                    serialPort.close();
                    inputStream.close();
                    br.close();
                    bw.close();
                    break;
                }
            }   

            //new CompareClass();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is my code to read data. Now please tell me where i can use Executor.

Comment: I don't know how to use Executor, is there any other easy way. I want that once my software get connected with hardware , it should check to read from serial port till suppose 10mins. After that it should show message that please reconnect again. And if getting input it should read and save it to txt file. In both the cases it should close ports,input stream,buffered reader etc

Comment: `in.close();` <- I doubt this will work if you close the inputstream ...

Answer (score -1):

Possibly using Timer (Schedule) in conjunction with your read loop.
Using as following -> timer.schedule('your_read_task','time_when_you_want_to_end')

Comment: java.util.Timer? In that case second parameter does not make sense.

Comment: public void schedule(TimerTask task, Date time)
task - task to be scheduled. 
time - time at which task is to be executed.

Comment: Yes, *executed* not "ended".

Comment: True. I should have worded it better. My point was to read it with in the timer context.

Comment: I did that way but than not reading the serial port if I do so. What is Date time. I put 50000 in place of Date time. May be this is the reason. I have change 5000 to 50000 but nothing has changed. I put new Thread( new InputStream in).start in run method of Timer task.

Comment: My requirement is once serial port is connected one should send any time data within a specified period buT. If no data is coming by that time than it should terminate or show the msg that no data is coming